# NodeJS Iterate through City in JSON, Return Cities and Users in each City

Tags: node.js, json, object

I have the below snippet from a JSON Object that has 3,500 records in it.

```json
[
    {
      "use:firstName": "Bob",
      "use:lastName": "Smith",
      "use:categoryId": 36,
      "use:company": "BobSmith",
      "use:webExId": "Bob.Smith@email.com",
      "use:address": {
        "com:addressType": "PERSONAL",
        "com:city": "US-TX",
        "com:country": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "use:firstName": "Jane",
      "use:lastName": "Doe",
      "use:categoryId": 36,
      "use:webExId": "Jane.Doe@email.com",
      "use:address": {
        "com:addressType": "PERSONAL",
        "com:city": "US-CA",
        "com:country": "1_1"
      }
    }
    {
        "use:firstName": "Sam",
        "use:lastName": "Sneed",
        "use:categoryId": 36,
        "use:webExId": "Sam.Sneed@email.com",
        "use:address": {
          "com:addressType": "PERSONAL",
          "com:city": "US-CA",
          "com:country": "1_1"
        }
      }
]
```

I am using NodeJS and I have been stuck on figuring out the best way to:
 1. Iterate through `['use:address']['com:city'` to map out and identify all of the Cities. (In the example above, I have two: **US-TX** and **US-CA** in the three records provided)
 2. Then identify how many records match each City (In the example above, I would have **US-TX**: 1 and **US-CA**: 2)

The only code I have is the easy part which is doing a `forEach` loop through the JSON data, defining `userCity` variable (to make it easier for me) and then logging to console the results (which is really unnecessary but I did it to confirm I was looping through JSON properly).

```js
function test() {
    const webexSiteUserListJson = fs.readFileSync('./src/db/webexSiteUserDetail.json');
    const webexSiteUsers = JSON.parse(webexSiteUserListJson);
    webexSiteUsers.forEach((userDetails) => {
        let userCity = userDetails['use:address']['com:city'];
        console.log(userCity);
    })
};
```

I've been searching endlessly for help on the topic and probably not formulating my question properly. Any suggestions are appreciated on how to:
 1. Iterate through `['use:address']['com:city'` to map out and identify all of the Cities. 
 2. Then identify how many records match each City (In the example above, I would have **US-TX**: 1 and **US-CA**: 2)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the `webexSiteUsers` array into an object that is keyed by city, where each value is the number of times the city occurs. Something like the below should work.

```
const counts = webexSiteUsers.reduce((countMemo, userDetails) => {
  let userCity = userDetails['use:address']['com:city'];
  if (countMemo[userCity]) {
    countMemo[userCity] = countMemo[userCity] + 1;
  } else {
    countMemo[userCity] = 1;
  }
  return countMemo;
}, {});
```

`counts` will then be an object that looks like this.

```
{
  "US-TX": 1,
  "US-CA": 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Benjamin! I would have had no idea about `reduce` if it weren't for you. I'd been searching Google for almost a month looking for an answer. Thank you again. You make it look easy.